# How to change background color of button while clicking on it

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a input box which consists of many buttons. i want it to behave like when clicking on a button i want that button row's background to be changed and revert it when clicking on other button.
I tried many approach but nothing works.

Can anyone help me in this scenario?[image: Attached image is the reference where in input box buttons are there when clicking on particular button button row's background changes]

Here is my code:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".green");
for (button in buttons) {
  buttons[button].onclick = function() {
    console.log('test') var yellowButton = document.querySelectorAll(".yellow")[0];
    if (this.className == "green") {
      if (yellowButton) yellowButton.className = "green";
      this.className = "yellow";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @manish Please post some relevant code that you have tried

Comment: Post this attempt in your question. Very few will look at comments but everybody will look at your question and help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do some sort of toggling like this?

```js
function myFunc(btn) {
  //get the current active button
  var activeBtn = document.querySelector('button.active-btn');
  if (activeBtn) {
    activeBtn.classList.remove('active-btn'); //remove the .active-btn class
  }
  btn.classList.add('active-btn'); //add .active-btn class to the button clicked
}
```

```css
.active-btn.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.active-btn.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active-btn.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.active-btn.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

button {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" class="red" onclick="myFunc(this)">Red</button>
  <button type="button" class="blue" onclick="myFunc(this)">Blue</button>
  <button type="button" class="green" onclick="myFunc(this)">Green</button>
  <button type="button" class="yellow" onclick="myFunc(this)">Yellow</button>
</div>
```

You can also try adding a default "active-btn" class to the button you want and also adding a disable/enable effect like so:

```js
function myFunc(btn) {
  //remove .active-btn class if button is currently active
  if (btn.className.indexOf('active-btn') !== -1) {
    btn.classList.remove('active-btn');
  } else {
    //get the current active button
    var activeBtn = document.querySelector('button.active-btn');
    if (activeBtn) {
      activeBtn.classList.remove('active-btn'); //remove the .active-btn class on currently active button
    }
    btn.classList.add('active-btn'); //add .active-btn class to the button clicked if not active
  }
}
```

```css
.active-btn.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.active-btn.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active-btn.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.active-btn.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

button {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" class="active-btn red" onclick="myFunc(this)">Red</button>
  <button type="button" class="blue" onclick="myFunc(this)">Blue</button>
  <button type="button" class="green" onclick="myFunc(this)">Green</button>
  <button type="button" class="yellow" onclick="myFunc(this)">Yellow</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks For Help I'll try and let you know the result.

Comment: No problem @manishjoshi. Mark this as the correct answer and/or upvote if this helped you.

Comment: Thanks @Geoman Yabes This approach is working. Accepting this answer